# Set firebase realtime database rules for a particular node

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

Can we set firebase realtime database rules for a particular node? I want to set rule for a particular node that if children count of that particular node exceeds 10 then no other user can write into that node.

can anyone suggest me a way to do it?

Comment: have look [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/)

Answer (score -1):

Try this at the target node

```
{
     "write" : "data.numChildren() < 10"
}
```